# How can I pass a gradle file collection to exec?

Tags: gradle

How can I pass a FileCollection's elements to Exec?

I have this task which takes input from another task and calls a Perl script to produce three output files.

```
task acct(type: Exec) {
    inputs.files getAcct
    outputs.files "file1", "file2", "file3"
    executable "perl" 
    args "makeAcct.pl", inputs.files.singleFile, "file1", "file2", "file3"
}
```

This works but I don't want to duplicate the file names in `outputs.files` and `args`.

I've tried passing these in `args`

- `outputs.files.getFiles().toArray()` but that gets an Object[] and passes `[Ljava.lang.Object;@340bccc9`
- `outputs.files.asType(Object[])` gets a File[] and passes `[Ljava.io.File;@6280a9b8`
- `outputs.files.getFiles()` gets a Collection and passes `[file1, file2, file3]`
- `outputs.files.getAsPath()` gets a single String and passes `file1:file2:file3`
- `outputs.files.getAsPath().replaceAll(File.pathSeparator, " ")` gets `file1 file2 file3` but this is still passed as one argument, not as three arguments
- `outputs.files.singleFile` throws because there are more than one file (it works for the inputs because there is only one input file)
- `outputs.files.getFiles().toArray()[0], outputs.files.getFiles().toArray()[1], outputs.files.getFiles().toArray()[2]` works but is even more ugly than just putting in the file names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that:

- `FileCollection` is-a `java.util.Collection`.
- There is an `Exec#args` overload that takes an `Iterable` (see `Exec` in the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html)).
- By convention, configuration methods that accept multiple arguments are additive.

This gives:

```
task acct(type: Exec) {
    inputs.files getAcct
    outputs.files "file1", "file2", "file3"
    executable "perl" 
    args "makeAcct.pl"
    args inputs.files
    args outputs.files
}
```

Alternatively, spreading the collections (`args "makeAcct.pl", *(inputs.files), *(outputs.files)`) should work as well.

Comment: Using multiple args works. `*outputs.files` gets a syntax error, and `outputs*.files` passes "[task ':acct' output files]" to the Perl script.

Comment: Probably needs to be `*(outputs.files)`. `outputs*.files` is the wrong tool for the job.